# OperationalError: no such table: customer

Tags: python, database, dataframe, sqlite

Thanks for reading this.  I’m learning python and have run into a bit of a blocker.
I’m trying to set up a basic database to join some data together and query it.
I’ve entered the code below but get this error when I run it
no such table: customer

There is more to the error message but I think if I solve this the rest will go away…Hopefully

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///HFSS.db")
conn = engine.connect()
customer = pd.read_excel('customer_orders.xlsx',index_col = 'CU_GTIN' * 1)
customer ## running this shows me a table
```

When I try to run a simple query in SQLite I get the error.

```
query = '''SELECT EccCustomerLevel3Name
FROM customer'''
pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

Thanks for your time
D

Comment: If you want to create a table from the dataframe you will need to call `customer.to_sql(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer snakecharmerb! Works perfectly now!